# Api returns a object of object instead of array

Tags: java, json, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm trying to use retrofit2 and Gson to interface with a online api I don't control. The result contains an object that is made up of other objects opposed to an array.

A snippet of the json that is returned looks like this:

```
{
"error": false,
"count": 116,
"info": "116 strains was found for your search.",
"strains": {
    "Master_Thai_-_Angels_Flight": {
        "name": "Angel's Flight",
        "brname": "Master Thai",
        "id": "Angels_Flight",
        "brid": "Master_Thai"
        },
    "DJ_Short_-_Azure_Haze": {
        "name": "Azure Haze",
        "brname": "DJ Short",
        "id": "Azure_Haze",
        "brid": "DJ_Short"
        },
    "MTG_Seeds_-_B-4": {
        "name": "B-4",
        "brname": "MTG Seeds",
        "id": "B-4",
        "brid": "MTG_Seeds"
        }
}
}
```

I tried to create some pojo's that look like:

```
data class StrainSearchResult(
    @SerializedName("error")
    @Expose
    val error: Boolean,
    @SerializedName("count")
    @Expose
    val count: String,
    @SerializedName("info")
    @Expose
    val info: String,
    @SerializedName("strains")
    @Expose
    val strains: Strains
)
```

and

```
data class Strains(
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    val strainName: String,
    @SerializedName("brname")
    @Expose
    val breederName: String,
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    val strainId: String,
    @SerializedName("brid")
    @Expose
    val breederId: String
)
```

If I call the api my response object looks like:

```
StrainSearchResult:
count: # of results,
error: false,
info: "A string",
strains: A single object of Strain that lists all properties as null
```

[See here for a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etuQS.jpg)

How can I parse the "strains" json object into a list of "strains"?

Comment: The object that you posted isn't valid JSON (the names aren't quoted). Fixing that, `strains` can be treated as a `Map<String, Strain>`.

Comment: Sorry, I have a json formatter plugin that I copy/pasted from. So I should return a map instead of a Strains object?

Comment: Holy moly, returning a Map<String, Strains> gives me a Map I can work with. This might not be ideal...but I think I can make this work. Thanks!

Comment: Note that your class really ought to be named `Strain`, because each instance represents *one* strain. Your *map* or other collection of them is plural.

Comment: If you have a json formatter that forms this code, get a better one, because even with the workaround the JS-esque code you're showing _is not JSON_ =)